# There is no h1 tag in the home page

Tags: joomla-3.x, seo, header-tags

There is no h1 or h2 tags in my site's home page.
I guess that's a very bad thing for SEO.

[image]

By searching i found out that one way to solve this is to override root/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php file and change the article titles to h1.

But i think this solves the problem in articles. what about home page?

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

There's no need for all that, although it is a great way to customize core views.  Joomla has support for H1 & H2 tags most certainly.

To edit your H1 tag for a page, go to that menu's management page in the back-end.  Once there navigate to the **Page Display** tab:

[image]

You can show the default page heading (which is the menu title) or add a custom version in the text input below.

The H2 tags are controlled at component level, and for articles, would be the article title.

Comment: I turned on "show page heading" in "Home" page, but still no h1 tag in the home page. :/

Comment: Are u using a 3rd party or custom template?

Comment: Yes.. i'm using sj market template, designed by smortaddons

Comment: i think the code part that is suppose to show the Page Heading, is missing somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The above post is correct but I personally ( based on SEO ) like more control. At times I do not use the same title name as the most important text on the page which is what H1 ultimately is. So I hide the title and use the H1 method with the editor. You can style it individually and word it to better match your page content.[image]

Comment: you mean u hide the article's title using css?

Comment: No I use it the hide method so the meta title still shows to search bots but not on the page. In the users pic above... set "Show Page Heading" to no but fill out the "Browser Page Title".

Comment: You can customize the header text using the Page Heading text field in the tab I posted above.

Comment: That is true but when doing it the method I recommended you end up with two title names plus H1. Without sounding disrespectful I would like to see your method vs mine in regards to Google rankings.

Comment: @norcal No disrespect perceived and I'm curious too, however it sounds you might be more versed in Google Rankings.  Question, when you say "more control" are you referring to the wording used for the H1 and H2 tags?  Or are you also including HTML element taxonomy?

Comment: @norcaljohnny The <h1> should not be ‘the most important text on the page’. It is the header for the parent sectioning element, which may or may not be the entire page. You also should not be styling header elements in your editor; inline styles are bad.

Comment: @seth inline styles are not bad when using for instance on an ID opposed to a class.. whether it is placed in the css file or inline, the idea is ultimately the same with  amount of code. As for H1 and it being the most important text, ultimately it surely is the most important and is closely tied to SEO regardless of what many claim. I say that only becuase I use to follow the standard formula for page rank and none seem to work.

Comment: @Brian. I use it for many reasons as mentioned, and as you can see no matter what happens user still could not get it to work using the other method of displaying page title to yes. This how I have insanely good results and have proof. I match the url to my h1 and article title, and the text below h1 I use words to match my h1 and use that as my meta description. The result is high content relevancy and for this I get most of my clients on the first page within the first round of Google indexing.